# cflow can't recognize function call in loop

Tags: call-graph, cflow

```
int main() {
    
    for (int i = 1; i < 10 ; i++) {
      test1();
    } 
    for (int i = 1; i < 10 ; i++)
      test2();

    return 0;
}
```

So for the code above, cflow can see test2() but not test1(). See output below:

```
$cflow tmp.c
main() <int main () at tmp.c:1>:
    test2()
$ cflow --version
cflow (GNU cflow) 1.7
Copyright (C) 2005-2021 Sergey Poznyakoff
```

Is this a bug or something very stupid I have done?

Thanks for you input!

Answer (score 0):

If you remove int i from the loops and define i = 0 outside the for loop, it shows both calls.

Answer (score 0):

Answering this a little bit late. I also ran into the same issue and got a work around.
I have a huge code base and can't change all for loops to C89 standard, plus I have thirdparty code I don't want to edit.

So just call cflow with the define `-D"for(x,...)=for(;;)"`.